# Specified path is invalid - Robocopy

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, robocopy

I'm trying to copy a file from one directory to another using robocopy . This is the command from C#. /C is added since process is invoked from code.

```
/C ROBOCOPY \\\\35.8.1.147\\e$\\DATA\\Logs C:\\Copy /A-:SH Log1.log
```

Did not add quotes since file name does not have any spaces. But it fails with the following error

```
ERROR 161 (0x000000A1) Accessing Source Directory\\\\35.8.1.147\\e$\\DATA\\Logs
The specified path is invalid.
Waiting 30 seconds...
```

C# code for invoking process

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/C ROBOCOPY {0} {1} /A-:SH {2}",
                        srcDirectory, "C:\\Copy", srcFileName);
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
```

But I'm able to manually access the file through explorer. What would be the reason?

Comment: edited. Thank you

Comment: Your code runs fine for me

Comment: What happens if you run `DIR \\35.8.1.147\e$\DATA\Logs`?

Comment: It works perfectly fine and it lists the files in that location.